best linear predictor for vectors
Given a random variable $Y \in \mathbb{R}$ and a random vector $\boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^k$, the best linear predictor $\boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{\beta}$ of $Y$ ($\boldsymbol{\beta}\in \mathbb{R}^k$) is such that $\boldsymbol{\beta} = \operatorname{argmin}_{\boldsymbol{b}\in \mathbb{R}^k} \operatorname{E}[(Y - \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{b})^2]$. One can show by calculation that $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{X}^T])^{-1} \operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{X} Y]$.
Now let $\boldsymbol{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector. I would like to define in general a best linear predictor $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} \boldsymbol{X}$ that approximates $\boldsymbol{Y}$, where $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ should have an expression similar to that of $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ after proper calculations, that is, $\boldsymbol{\Gamma} = \operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{Y} \boldsymbol{X}^T] (\operatorname{E}[\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{X}^T])^{-1}$. If it is possible, what should be the correct definition of such linear predictor?

isn't this just a multiple linear regression ?

It is worth mentioning that some assumptions need to be placed before one can use this particular estimator.

@Stratossupportsthestrike For what I know, a multiple linear regression refers to linear models with multiple independent variables, while what I ask for is a linear model that has a vector as its dependent variable.

What you mean is called generalised linear regression.

I think you want to look for multivariate (not multiple!) linear regression. A good starting point could be the wiki page on Seemingly Unrelated Regressions.

Seems like the answer to your question is given in this thread.
